# Array of Objects Random Image Generator with Captions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random

I am trying to build a random image generator that also has two other fields or captions associated with it that display on page. I think the solution is to create an array of objects, but I am pretty rusty on objects and classes so I'm not sure I'm building it right. Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
    <img id="winnerImage" src="http://placehold.it/1500x1200" alt="Winners at Rhythm City Casino Resort&reg;" width="1500" height="1200" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-8 col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="display-3" id="winnerHeader">Another Big Winner at Rhythm City!</h2>
    <h3 id="winnerCaption">Debbie R. &bull; $5,000&nbsp;Winner.</h3>
    <p class="text-center"><a href="winners.html" class="btn btn-primary">View Winners Gallery</a></p>
</div>
```

and my script file

```
window.onload = choosePic;

function BigWinner(source, name, amount) {
    this.source = source;
    this.name = name;
    this.amount = amount;
}

var winnersArray = new Array (
    BigWinner("JohnD_1280.40_DeWittIA_September2017.JPG", "John D.", "$1,280"),
    BigWinner("KaronB_13004.81_DavenportIA_September2017.JPG", "Karon B.", "$13,004"),
    BigWinner("KyleG_1742_NewBostonIL_September2017.JPG", "Kyle G.", "$1,742"),
    BigWinner("MarciaP_2000.40_LeClaireIA_November2017.JPG", "Marcia P.", "$2,000"),
    BigWinner("ShaneE_4164,76_CamancheIA_September2017.JPG", "Shane E.", "$4,164")
);

function choosePic() {
    randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * winnersArray.length));
    document.getElementById("winnerImage").src = "img/Casino/Winners/" + winnersArray[randomNum].source;
    document.getElementById("winnerCaption").innerHTML = winnersArray[randomNum].name + " &bull; " + winnersArray[randomNum].amount + " Winner";
}
```

Comment: Just add `new` Keyword to all statement inside `Array` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things, your array syntax can be simplified and you'll need to use the `new` keyword when making new BigWinners.

```
var winnersArray = [
    new BigWinner("JohnD_1280.40_DeWittIA_September2017.JPG", "John D.", "$1,280"),
    new BigWinner("KaronB_13004.81_DavenportIA_September2017.JPG", "Karon B.", "$13,004"),
    new BigWinner("KyleG_1742_NewBostonIL_September2017.JPG", "Kyle G.", "$1,742"),
    new BigWinner("MarciaP_2000.40_LeClaireIA_November2017.JPG", "Marcia P.", "$2,000"),
    new BigWinner("ShaneE_4164,76_CamancheIA_September2017.JPG", "Shane E.", "$4,164")
];
```